# Dotless media query is not output

Tags: c#, dotless

I have this rule in my code.

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) { foobar }
```

I see the stuff between the braces (e.g. foobar) when I look at the css output by dotless.  But it's not inside of a media tag, so it goes to all media types.

Comment: How strange. What if you used `@media (max-width: 600px)`, which basically says the same thing?